# Azure Machine Learning Studio Custom Module Upload Error 0114 : An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When trying to upload a custom R module to Azure Machine Learning Studio what causes the following error.

> [ModuleOutput]

```
"ErrorId":"BuildCustomModuleFailed","ErrorCode":"0114","ExceptionType":"ModuleException","Message":"Error 0114: Custom module build failed with error(s): An item with the same key has already been added."}} [ModuleOutput] Error: Error 0114: Custom module build failed with error(s): An item with the same key has already been added.
```

I have tried renaming the module so a name that does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate key exception is a red herring. [Build error 0114](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn962112.aspx) is a general error that occurs if there is a system exception while building the custom module. The real issue my module was compressed using the built in compress folder option in the Mac Finder. To fix this compress the file using the command line interface for `zip` in Terminal in the following very specific manner.

> The following example:

```
cd ScoredDatasetMetadata/
zip ScoredDatasetMetadata *
mv ScoredDatasetMetadata.zip ../
```

Builds a zip file with the correct file structure.